# MySQL - How to show in multiple columns html table, single column of mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, html-table

I want to know how to show in my php file with html a table with multiple columns but in that columns show only a single column results from mysqli

What I have for now is:

```
<?php

include "dbinc.php";

$con=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);

$letramasculinos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nome FROM nomes WHERE nome LIKE '$_POST[letra]%' AND sexo = 'm';");
$letrafemininos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nome FROM nomes WHERE nome LIKE '$_POST[letra]%' AND sexo = 'f';");

     (more code...)

echo "<table style='display: inline-block;' width='150px' border='1' bgcolor='#6699FF'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($letramasculinos))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['nome'] . "</center></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

echo "<table style='display: inline-block;' width='150px' border='1' bgcolor='#FF99FF'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($letrafemininos))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['nome'] . "</center></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}

     (more code...)

?>
```

In this example code this shows 2 HTML tables with 1 column but as entries are too much I want divide that column by 3 columns (or by 4 or 5, etc...) in each table.

How can I do this?

Example:

What I have and What I want

```
  I have this:      I Want Something like this:

  +---------+     +--------+---------+--------+
  | Diogo   |     | Diogo  | André   | João   |
  +---------+     +--------+---------+--------+
  | André   |     | Filipe | Carlos  | Gaspar |
  +---------+     +--------+---------+--------+
  | João    |     | Fabio  | Fernado |        |
  +---------+     +--------+---------+--------+
  | Filipe  |
  +---------+
  | Carlos  |
  +---------+
  | Gaspar  |
  +---------+
  | Fabio   |
  +---------+
  | Fernado |
  +---------+
```

Comment: If I were you I'd try fiddling around with some CSS first! (And I'd put this data in `<ul>` and `<li>` items anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a php guy but some algo might help.1) get the count of records for male /female

```
"SELECT count(*)FROM nomes WHERE nome LIKE '$_POST[letra]%' AND sexo = 'f'; ..... same for 'male'.
```

save this to mcount and fcount variables.

```
if mcount >10
then 
 noOfColms=mcount /10;
 i=0;
 put "<table>"
loop records 
i=i+1;
put "<tr>"
if(i<noOfColms)
   put "<td>" + data +"</td>"
if i==noOfColms
put "</tr>"     
end loop   
put "</table>"
```

else
 show list view

do same thing for fcount

Comment: I do not understood, can you explain more please?

Comment: basically get the number of records for male and female, and then if the records are less than 10 display as is in list form. if they are more say 50 .then noofcols=50/10 = 5 coloumns . start looping through your records create a td 5 times (coloumns) and fill the data . once you reach end of 5 column create a new row <tr> repeat till all the records are built

Comment: I created a variable like this: `$mcount = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*)FROM nomes WHERE nome LIKE '$_POST[letra]%' AND sexo = 'm';");` and other with fcount and now what I do?

Comment: now i started to understand but not understood how implement the code in my php yet... but can't be always 3 columns?

Comment: yes divide by 10 is the part which tells how many no of columns you want .so you can have any factor to determine what this magic number is 10 or oterwise(say width of page/varcharsize of your name field+ seperater )